# Wedge product of $k$-forms

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I'm studying smooth manifolds with Lee's book. He defines a $k$-form on a manifold $M$ as a section $M \to \Lambda^k M$ (where $\Lambda^k M = \bigsqcup_{p\in M} \Lambda^k T_pM$ is the smooth vector bundle of alternating $k$-tensors).

Now he defines the wedge product of such forms pointwise by $(\omega \wedge \eta)_p = \omega_p \wedge \eta_p$. I don't see why this depends differentiably on $p$.

Kind regards,
Sebastian

Comment: I do not understand your question.. May be i am not matured enough to understand your question but can you please try to explain a bit more..

Comment: In coordinates, the wedge product of $\varphi_I dx_I$ and $\eta_J dx_J$ is zero if the indexing set $I \cap J$ is nonempty, and (maybe up to throwing in a factorial or two, depending on your conventions) $\varphi_I \eta_J dx_I \wedge dx_J$ if $I \cap J$ is empty. This clearly depends smoothly on the inputs.

Comment: @kklm I do not find anything unclear about it. It would probably help the OP and yourself to be more specific about what you find unclear.

Comment: @MikeMiller : As i have said, I may not be mature enough to understand this question... I do not understand what does it mean to say depends differentiably on $p$

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks for your comment! That it is sufficient to have smooth coefficients is not obvious to me. However 1-forms are just sections of the covector bundle and for those there is a Lemma in Lee's book (6.6) that asserts that a rough section into the covector bundle is smooth iff. its coefficients are smooth for some local representation. Now I have to figure out why this lifts up to $k$-forms (or what the relation between covector bundle and $\Lambda^k M$ is), but this seems to be possible. Probably I just have to sort my thoughts since vector bundles are relatively new to me.

Comment: Sure, it's always good to get practice. In general, for any smooth bundle, a section is smooth iff its representation in a (smooth) local trivialization is smooth.